# Getting this error: request for member 'at' in 'array3', which is of pointer type

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, compiler-errors

The function apply_all is supposed to multiple all the elements of array2 (of size2) to all the elements of array1 (of size1) and store them at a dynamically created vector (of size1*size2)
The compiler mention this line for error: array3.at(i)=array1.at(k)*array2.at(j);

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> *apply_all(vector<int>&array1,size_t &size1,vector<int>&array2,size_t &size2)
{
    vector<int> *array3{nullptr};
    array3=new vector<int>(size1*size2);  //heap memory allocated using vectors
    size_t i{0};
    for (size_t j=0;j<size2;j++){
        for (size_t k=0;k<size1;k++){
            array3.at(i)=array1.at(k)*array2.at(j);
            i++;
        }
    }
    return array3;
}
```

Comment: `array3` is a pointer. Use `->`.

Comment: Why don't you stick to vectors? Is there a reason for your messing around with manual memory management?

Comment: The question that I'm trying to solve has told me to use dynamic memory for array3 to test my knowledge as I'm new to this topic.

Comment: @ArpanBose --  `array3=new vector<int>[size1*size2];` -- That looks wrong.  You are creating `size1*size2`, vectors dynamically?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes I was trying to create the vector of size1*size2 dynamically.I don't understand what's wrong here. Please clarify

Comment: @ArpanBose Do you know the difference between `new T[x];` and `new T(x);`?  Note that I asked whether you are creating `size1 * size2` **vectors**, not if you are creating a single vector that has that size.  Big difference.

Comment: @ArpanBose You are using pointers and new where it is unnecessary, see answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allocating vectors is just crazy. Most of the advantages of using a vector (like not having to manually manage memory) disappear in an instant. Create your vector on the stack instead, like this

```
vector<int> apply_all(vector<int>&array1,size_t &size1,vector<int>&array2,size_t &size2)
{
    vector<int> array3(size1*size2);
    ...
    return array3;
}
```

This also fixes the errors you were asking about.

Vectors allocate their memory from the heap, but there is no need to allocate the vector **itself** from the heap.